# Famous the calling thread cannot access this object because a different issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await

This is how my code is setup. However I am getting an exception when updating myUIElement in Method2.

> "the calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

Should anything after await always be called on UI thread? What am I doing wrong here?

```
 private async void Method1()
        {

    // I want to wait until Method2 is completed before doing anything else in Method1 
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method2());

        }

 private async void Method2()
        {
            // Reading few things from configuration etc
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeAPILoadDataFromSomewhere());
                myUIElement.Text = "something useful has happened"; 


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `StartNew` when you don't actually want the code in question to run in a non-UI thread.  Just remove it entirely.

Also note that you should only have `async void` methods as top level event handlers.  Any async method that you intend to `await` should return a `Task`.

You should also generally be using `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew` where possible.

```
//This should return a Task and not void if it is used by another asynchronous method
private async void Method1()
{
    await Method2();
    DoSomethingElse();
}

private async Task Method2()
{
    await Task.Run(() => SomeAPILoadDataFromSomewhere());
    myUIElement.Text = "something useful has happened";             
}
```

Comment: this is causing the application to be hung in Method2 when UI is been upated.

Comment: @johnsmith Then you're not calling `Method1` from the UI thread, and you should be.  Or you're blocking the UI thread when you shouldn't be blocking the UI thread.